# Autocomplete in eclipse with MOAI Lua

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, lua

So I am working with MOAI 2D game engine and I am using Eclipse with the Koneki plugin to interpret Lua.

Right now, autocomplete works with normal Lua libraries like math. and io. but what I want to do is set up autocomplete for the MOAI libraries.  I have created and imported my library into Eclipse but the autocomplete doesn't work and I don't know why. I must be missing a step.

So far, I've gone to Window > Preferences > Lua > Execution Environment and added my library. Then I right clicked on my project and went to properties. Then I went to Lua > Build Path and added my library to the project. At this point I tried to use autocomplete functionality by typing things like MOAISim. but I had no luck.

I've searched around alot with no results. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Autocompletion is provided by Execution Environments that include formatted documentation.

There is a library of execution environments [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/User_Area/Available_Execution_Environments). It looks like someone has contributed one for MOAI. To install an execution environment, see this [article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/Developer_Area/User_Guides/User_Guide_0.8#Execution_Environment).